# Conference Room Phones

Tags: meetings, phone

At my current place of work we have multiple conference rooms with Polycom conference phones.  The issue is, employees are removing the phones and taking them to other rooms and using them.  Doesn't seem like too big of a deal but when other employees come back to the original conference room to conduct a conference call the phones need to be "hooked up" again.

Is there a solution to preventing this from happening?  Locking the rooms is not an a feasible option.

Comment: Has anyone told employees not to remove the phones?

Comment: They are currently labeled with each conference room, that doesn't seem to deter it at times.

Comment: So nobody actually bothered to tell anyone not to remove the phones? I would start with that.

Comment: Is this your problem to fix? Are you in a position of authority to do anything about it? Judging by your comment below that's not the case and there isn't much value in the question if that's the case. John's practical solution would work but we're a site about dealing with interpersonal conflicts much more than logistical ones.

Comment: @Lilienthal - Assume that yes it is the OP's problem to address until the OP states otherwise.

Comment: @IDrinkandIKnowThings Eh, no. Why should I? All indications are that OP is not an OM but just an employee who's annoyed by the problem. OP is actually a registered user so should be able to update the question.

Comment: @Lilienthal - Because that is the policy.  Its one thing when someone says they are not a manager and can not make changes.  The OP has not said any qualifier like that.  Even if the OP can not make changes future users with the problem might find help from constructive answers.

Comment: @IDrinkandIKnowThings That discussion belongs on meta. My argument is that OP can and should clarify what problem he faces to avoid having useless or fragmented answers and that the general question you suggest is too broad. We can't possibly attempt to answer every management problem from every possible angle and for every possible variable. Questions need a clear scope to be answerable and this post doesn't currently qualify.

Comment: Why do the other rooms not have conference phones?

Comment: @Lilienthal - That is a valid concern.  I read your comment differently

Comment: Does anyone else at your office find this annoying? What are the solutions *they* have tried before?

Answer (score 6):

Those polycom spider phones have a slot for a Kensington lock. Affix said lock and attach to the desk (with permission from management/IT/facilities) and your days will be happy

Comment: I am in IT and if one of my phones was being picked up and carried off I would not hesitate to lock it down. For me the real question is why is there a need to take these phones? Is another location in need of one and the funds have not been given to do so?

Comment: That I am unsure of and relatively new within my organization.  That is another issue for me to look at.

Comment: I agree with @NickYoung. If you solve the problem causing people to take the phones to begin with, they'll stop disappearing.

Comment: When all else fails find the issue and pass it up the chain. Maybe this is not an issue and they can deal with the delays, maybe locks do not matter but rather an -Official- "don't move the phones rule" might be all that is needed.

Answer (score 2):

[This Answer from JohnHC](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/80507/16) covers how to handle the problem if your phones should not be used outside of their assigned conference room.  However in many offices there just are not enough resources(in this case IP Conference phones) for all of the conference rooms and thus need to be shared.  While I agree with them many of you that are probably shouting at your screen right now, "OMG how can a company expect you to do your job if they don't give you enough tools to get it done!"  The reality is many companies prefer to minimize the capitol output when installing telecom systems.  And so we are left with the task of dealing with these issues, and many times that includes moving telecom resources to the room where they are needed.

The first thing I would do is label each of these phones with the conference room the phone is "Assigned" to.   Put up signs near the exit door that are clearly visible saying something concise like "Return phone to this conference room after borrowing."

In any conference room that does not have a phone assigned to it post a sign near the exit that says something like "Remember to return any conference phones to its assigned conference room"

The combination of the clearly labeled phone, with the signs will probably alleviate most of the problem.  If it does not then its time to track how much time is being spent searching for and reclaiming phones for conference rooms, and use that information to justify increasing the number of conference phone resources available.  You managers are not trying to hamper business, just save some money, when those efforts start costing as much or more than they save then its time to make a change.